# Closures In Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am new to iOS coding and I am stuck in closures feature of SWIFT. I have referred to many tutorials and found that closures are self written codes which can be used in many ways eg. as arguments in function call,parameters in function definition,variables. I am giving below an example below with my associated thoughts about the code & questions. Please help me if I am wrong in my understanding. I know I am wrong at many points,so please rectify me.

**1.1st Part**

```
 func TEST(text1:String,text2:String,flag: (S1:String,S2:String)->Bool)//In this line,I think,I am using flag is a closure which is passed as parameter in a function. And if so why doesn't it follow the standard closure syntax?
    {
        if flag(S1: text1, S2: text2) == true//I want to check the return type what flag closure gets when it compares the both string during function call. Why can't I write as if flag == true as flag is the name of the closure and ultimately refers to the return type of the closure?
        {
            print("they are equal")
        }
        else
        {
          //
        }
    }
```

**2nd Part**

This part is the most troublesome part that really confuses me when I am calling the function. Here I am also using the same closure. What is happening over here? How is the closure being used? Is it capturing values or something else?

```
TEST("heyy", text2: "heyy") { (S1, S2) -> Bool in
    S1==S2
}
```

Thanks for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first function works like this :

arguments :

- String 1
- String 2
- a function that takes two Strings as arguments and returns a Bool

body :

execute the function (flag) with text1 and text2 and check the result.
The function doesn't know at all what you are testing, it only knows that two pieces of text are needed and a Bool will be returned.

---

So this function allows you to create a general way of handling different functions that all have two Strings as input. You can check for equality or if the first pieces of text is a part of the second and so on.

This is useful for many things and not so far from how array filtering / sorting / map works.

---

2nd Part :

This is just how you call a function with a closure.

```
TEST("heyy", text2: "heyy") { (S1, S2) -> Bool in
    S1 == S2
}
```

You can also call it like this :

```
func testStringEqualityFor(text:String, and:String) -> Bool {

    return text == and

}

TEST("hey", text2: "hey", flag: testStringEqualityFor)
```

Instead of using the trailing closure syntax to pass an unnamed function, you now pass a named function as one of the arguments.

---

It al becomes a lot clearer when you simplify it.

This is a function that takes another function as an argument.
Now we can call/use this function inside it. The argument function takes a bool as it's argument. So we give it a `true`

```
func simpleFunctionWithClosure(closure:(success:Bool) -> Void) {

    // use the closure
    closure(success: true)

}
```

When we use the function we need to pass it a function. In Swift you have the trailing closure syntax for that, but that is only available (and even then optional) to the first function as argument.

Trailing closure syntax means that instead of passing a named function you can write:

```
myFunction { arguments-for-closure-as-tuple -> return-for-closure-as-tuple in 
    function-body 
}
```

The closure will receive an argument of `Bool` and returns nothing so `Void`.

In the body we can handle the arguments and do stuff with them.
But it is important to remember that what is inside the closure is not called directly. It is a function declaration that will be executed by `simpleFunctionWithClosure`

```
// use the function
simpleFunctionWithClosure { (success) -> Void in
    if success {
        print("Yeah")
    } else {
        print("Ow")
    }
}
```

Or with a named function :

```
func argumentFunction(success:Bool) -> Void {
    if success {
        print("Yeah")
    } else {
        print("Ow")
    }
}

simpleFunctionWithClosure(argumentFunction)
```

Comment: I was writing an answer but decided to read yours before I invested any more time. This is spot on +1

Answer (score 2):

Your closure usage is ok. A closure is some code that can be passed to be executed somewhere else. In your case you can choose to pass the real test you want to the function `TEST`, simple string test or case-insensitive test, etc. This is one of the first usage of closure: obtain more genericity.

And yes closures capture something, it captures some part of the environnement, i.e. the context in which they are defined. Look:

```
var m = "foo"
func test(text1:String, text2:String, testtFunc: (s1:String, s2:String) -> Bool) {
    m = "bar"
    if testFunc(s1: text1, s2: text2) { print("the test is true") }
}

m = "baz"
test("heyy", text2: "heyy") { (s1, s2) -> Bool in
    Swift.print("Value for m is \(m)")
    return s1==s2
}
```

The closure captures `m` (a variable that is defined in the context in which you define the closure), this means that this will print `bar` because at the time the closure is executed, the captured `m` equals to `bar`. Comment `bar`-line and `baz` will be printed; comment `baz`-line and `foo` will be printed. The closure captures `m`, not its value, `m` by itself, and this is evaluated to the correct value when the closure is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler wouldn't have any expectation how your closure is for. For example in your first case, it could not estimate the closure's intake parameters is always just reflect to the first and second parameters of the TEST function when we are always able to write the following code :

```
func Test(str1:String,str2:String,closure:(String,String)->Bool){
    if closure(str[str1.startIndex...str1.startIndex.advanced(2)],str2[str2.startIndex.advanced(1)...str2.endIndex])
    { ... }else{ ... }
    //Just an example, everybody know no one write their code like this.
}
```

The second case, I thought you've just overlooked the syntax sugar:

For a trailing closure A->B:

```
{ a:A -> B in a.bValue() }
```

is equal to :

```
{ a:A -> B in return a.bValue() }
```

Also, I think this TEST function isn't a good example when the task of it can be done without using closure. I think you can write a map function by yourself for a better understand of why and when to use closure.